# Помогите нам улучшить страницы пользовательских профилей и настроек

Tags: обсуждение, профиль-участника, настройки-профиля

Перевод статьи с MSE: [Help us improve the user profile and settings](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/319375/260198).

---

Вы несомненно знаете про страницу профиля. Она открывается по клику на вашу аватарку.

[image: Открытие профиля]

[image: Страница профиля]

Возможно вы заходите на эту страницу для просмотра своей активности или для обновления Developer Story. Или же хотите сменить настройки почтового ящика или участия в Beta-тестировании, или для получения классной визитки<sup>TM</sup>. Может проверяете свой профиль в Stack Exchange. Не исключено, что вы никогда не делали этого раньше и просто изучаете возможности сайтов сети

По правде говоря, пользовательский профиль и настройки не слабо так захламлялись в последние годы. Из-за того, что эти страницы не были в приоритете, результатом стало то, что **эта область  стала служить различным целям, но не справляется с каждой из них достаточно хорошо**.

С запуском Teams у нас появилось ещё больше случаев, которые профиль и настройки должны покрывать, и они это делают весьма посредственно.
Мы хотим изменить это. Не только потому что Teams требуют этого, но и **потому что Stack Overflow и Stack Exchange долго нуждались в улучшенном и отзывчивом профиле**.

### Нам нужна ваша помощь

Мы решили узнать у участников сообщества о том, что вам нравится и не нравится в профилях в текущем их виде, и как его можно улучшить. В дополнение к участникам на Мете, мы поговорим с людьми с нашего email Research списка. Основная цель на данный момент - узнать, какие изменения будут полезны пользователям в первую очередь.

Если вы можете выделить пару минут, **[пожалуйста, пройдите опрос](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSfhOFRPeAv33yp-U3x0HRzCjjkeXzUhUtTTj_aodeVKBlbDzg/viewform?usp=sf_link)**. Помимо прочего, там будут вопросы:

- Опишите, что вам нравится и не нравится в профилях в текущем их виде.
- Представьте, что у вас может быть единый профиль или несколько уникальных. Какой вы предпочтёте и почему?

Мы заметили, что активные пользователи Меты с большей частотой просматривают страницы профилей и настроек, вот почему мы, в первую очередь, просим вас помочь.

**Пожалуйста, завершите опрос до пятницы (7 Декабря).**